# Codeigniter disallow identical table rows

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, database-design

I have the following table that allows users to add other users as friends

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| ID | User_ID     | Friend_ID         |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 102         | 213               |
| 2  | 64          | 23                |
| 3  | 4           | 344               |
| 4  | 102         | 213               |
| 5  | 102         | 90                |
| 6  | 64          | 88                |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
```

Notice above that user `102` has added user `213` twice. I want to dissallow duplicate rows. Using active record, how can I disallow addition of user as friend if the user is already a friend?

Comment: you have database design problem! Edit your database as others have suggested and when trying to insert duplicate rows into database you get errors. You can catch those errors then. And show appropriate fail message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you are using `id` as a primary key for your table. I can suggest to use a complex primary key, combining all the table fields. Still this is not a good design approach. As alternative you could make a table decomposition.

Comment: Or just drop the ID column and create composite primary key on two remaining cols.

Comment: would using UNIQUE Constraints on `user_ID` and `friend_ID` columns be a better choice?

Comment: @CyberJunkie. I don't think so, because it leads to additional redundancy. There is no reason to use `unique` if the primary key could do the same job. Moreover, `Id` column seems to be useless. Thus two-column table (user_id,friend_id) with the composite primary key is likely the best solution.

Comment: @tyz, I thought that columns with primary keys can hold only unique ids, so more users can't be friends with the same user id, should the same id appear again in the `Friend_ID` column. Is this false?

Comment: @CyberJunkie, you are right, primary key holds unique values only. But you should dive in more details. In general primary key is a combination of values from the column set. Simple primary key includes value from a single column. The composite one comprises several columns. Thus the table can include several identical `User_ID` values if the corresponding `Friend_ID` values are different. The converse is also true - there could be several identical `Friend_ID` values if the corresponding `User_ID` values aren't the same. The only thing is important - the whole value set should be unique.

Comment: @tyz, +1 Thanks for the explanation! I tried making two columns primary key in phpmyadmin but I get `there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key` then I added the sql `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, friend_id);` and nothing is altered. multiple primary keys is confusing.. and there are many debates about it. Setting both columns to `unique` or `UNIQUE Constraints` seems to work without issues.